# Is it possible to append different values to different keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary:

```
groups  = {'group1': array([450, 449.]), 'group2': array([490, 489.]), 'group3': array([568, 567.])}
```

I have to iterate over a txt file that I have loaded using `numpy.loadtxt()` with many values:

```
subjects = 
[1.0, -1.0
2.0, 1.0
3.0, 2.0
...
565.0, 564.0
566.0, 565.0
567.0, 566.0
568.0, 567.0]
```

What I want to do is to check if the value in the first column of "subject" is equal to the value of the second column of each array in my dictionary.

So basically when the condition is met the line of "subjects" should be added to the appropriate array of the dictionary...

The output that I expect is this:

```
groups  = {'group1': array([450, 449.], [449, 448]), 'group2': array([490, 489.], [489, 488]), 'group3': array([568, 567.], [567, 566])}
```

Comment: First off, where does that array(...) object come from? Please include the module imports in your code you make it reproducible.

Comment: the array is a txt file that I import using numpy.loadtxt()

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it by parts

Note: I've done partitally. Analyze this code. Expected result is colse. I've observed array is splitted. I'm redaing dcoumention & looking way to split. Meanwhile explore this logic.Modify accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array


groups  = {'group1': array([450, 449.]), 'group2': array([490, 489.]), 'group3': array([568, 567.])}

lv =  np.array(list(groups.values()), dtype=object)
lv1 =lv.copy()
lv[:, [1, 0]] = lv[:, [0, 1]]
lv=np.concatenate((lv1, lv), axis=1)

groups = {k : [] for k in groups}
groups = {e: lv[i] for i, e in enumerate(groups)}


print(groups)
```

output #

```
{'group1': array([450.0, 449.0, 449.0, 450.0], dtype=object), 'group2': array([490.0, 489.0, 489.0, 490.0], dtype=object), 'group3': array([568.0, 567.0, 567.0, 568.0], dtype=object)}
```